# JavaFX FlowPane Autosize

Tags: java, javafx-8

The problem I'm having is that the FlowPane is leaving a lot of excess space, it could possibly be the Popup, although I think the popup size is the content size.

For the sake of debugging I've wrapped the text in a BorderPane to show the bounds of the text.

The component I'm focusing on is the error popup.

[image: Screenshot]
CSS

```
.warning-popup {
    -fx-padding: 10px;
    -fx-hgap: 10px;
    -fx-vgap: 10px;
    -fx-background-color: #704745;
    -fx-border-color: #C8C8C8;
    -fx-background-radius: 2px;
    -fx-border-radius: 2px;
}


.warning-popup .text {
    -fx-fill: #000000;
}
```

Java Code

```
public static void showWarningPopup(Node owner, String message, double screenX, double screenY) {
    // create message text
    Text text = new Text(message);
    text.getStyleClass().add("text");
    // wrap text in container
    Pane textContainer = new BorderPane(text);
    textContainer.setStyle("-fx-background-color: orange;");
    // create error image
    ImageView image = new ImageView("/resources/error-14.png");
    image.getStyleClass().add("image-view");
    // create content
    FlowPane content = new FlowPane(image, textContainer);
    content.getStyleClass().add("warning-popup");
    content.autosize();
    // create and show the popup
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.setHideOnEscape(true);
    popup.setAutoHide(true);
    popup.setAutoFix(true);
    popup.getContent().add(content);
    popup.show(owner, screenX, screenY);
}
```

Thank you for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Background**

The issue you are facing is because of the default `WrapLength` of FlowPane, which is set at **400**. This property also sets the `width` of the FlowPane to `400`.

*From the docs:*

> FlowPane's prefWrapLength property establishes it's preferred width (for horizontal) or preferred height (for vertical).

**Solution**

You can decrease the wrapLength to the desired value by using

```
flowPane.setPrefWrapLength(YOUR_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ItachiUchiha's answer, you may get rid of all panes and use `Label` for your simple use case:

```
public static void showWarningPopup( Node owner, String message, double screenX, double screenY )
{
    // create error image
    ImageView image = new ImageView( "/resources/error-14.png" );
    image.getStyleClass().add( "image-view" );

    // create content
    Label label = new Label( message, image );
    label.setBackground(
            new Background(
                    new BackgroundFill(
                            Color.ORANGE,
                            new CornerRadii( 10 ),
                            new Insets( -10 )
                    )
            )
    );

    // create and show the popup
    Popup popup = new Popup();
    popup.setHideOnEscape( true );
    popup.setAutoHide( true );
    popup.setAutoFix( true );
    popup.getContent().add( label );
    popup.show( owner, screenX, screenY );
}
```

You can prefer using css style classes instead of code based styling, of course.