# JavaFX - FlowPane Autosize

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, flowpane

Here's my problem: I would like to get a Pane with horizontal orientation and a width fitting with his content (like FlowPane), but if the width is too high, the Pane wraps its content. I don't want to calculate the 'prefWidth' or 'prefWrappingLength' by the children width because they are plentiful.

In the thread [JavaFX FlowPane Autosize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29537264/javafx-flowpane-autosize), they are giving solutions for wrapping text, but not for layouts.

Have you some tips for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are looking for an answer, here's what I finally did, ignoring the plentiful children constraint:

```
class RuleBox extends FlowPane {
    int maxWrapLength;
    int margin = 30;

    RuleBox(int maxWrapLength) {
        super();
        this.maxWrapLength = maxWrapLength;
        getChildren().addListener((ListChangeListener<? super Node>) observable -> actualizeWrapLength(observable.getList()));
    }

    private void actualizeWrapLength(ObservableList<? extends Node> list) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try { Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {}
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                int totalWidth = 0;
                for(Node n : list) {
                    if(n instanceof Control) totalWidth+=((Control)n).getWidth();
                    else if(n instanceof Region) totalWidth+=((Region)n).getWidth();
                }
                if(totalWidth+margin>maxWrapLength) setPrefWrapLength(maxWrapLength);
                else setPrefWrapLength(totalWidth+margin);
            });
        }).start();
    }

    void actualizeWrapLength() {
        actualizeWrapLength(getChildren());
    }
}
```

This is a pretty dirty code, especially for the `Thread.sleep(50)` used to have the final width of children. So if someone owns a better solution, please give it!